# Hybrization of H in HNO

Tags: orbitals, hybridization

There is a problem that states: Find the molecular geometry of each molecule and the hybridization of each atom in the molecule. The two molecules are HNO and HCN. I found HNO to be sp<sup>3</sup> hybridized and HCN to be sp hybridized. However, it says that only N and O are hybridized in the first. While all three are hybridized in the second. Why is hydrogen listed as sp hybridized?

Comment: That is a very good question; I can only assume an error in your book. Note that hybridisation *should always be discussed on a per-atom level*, and note that both the $\ce{O}$ in $\ce{HNO}$ and the $\ce{N}$ in $\ce{HCN}$ can also be assigned various possible hybridisations. P.S: Welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Take a [tour] and refer to the [help] for any questions about the site.

Answer (score 2):

Hybridization refers to the orbitals that each atom is using to make bonds.  In $\ce{HNO}$, the $\ce{N}$ and $\ce{O}$ are $sp^2$ hybridized.  This means they form a sigma bond with an $sp^2$ orbital from each and the pi bond from the interaction of the non-hybridized $p$ orbital on each.  The $\ce{N}$ also has a $sp^2$ orbital overlap with the $1s$ of $\ce{H}$, which forms a sigma bond.  Each of the lone pairs on the $\ce{N}$ and $\ce{O}$ is in an $sp^2$ orbital.

In $\ce{HCN}$ the carbon is $sp$ hybridized, as is the $\ce{N}$.  $\ce{C}$ and $\ce{N}$ form a sigma bond with $sp$ overlap, and the pi bond from the interaction of both of their non-hybridized $p$ orbitals (to form a triple bond).  The lone pair of $\ce{N}$ is in an $sp$ orbital, and the $\ce{C-H}$ bond is from an $sp$ overlap with the $1s$ of $\ce{H}$.

None of these molecules have $sp^3$ hybridization.

Comment: Note that OP explicitly also asked why hydrogen is listed as hybridised. Care to expand on that?

Comment: Hydrogen only forms bonds with its 1s orbital.  It can't hybridize to form bonds  as its electron fills a 1 s orbital which is too different in energy from the 2s and 2p oritals to mix.  I believe either OP misinterpreted something regarding this statement or there was an error in the book.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include that ;)